# How to revalidate a field after radio selection changes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a form where I am trying to validate whether an account entered is a local account or a domain account. The form looks like this:

[image: Form preview]

The form uses basic MVC validation. My viewmodel looks as such:

```
[Display(Name = "Account Type")]
public string AccountType { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required")]
[Remote ("ValidateUserID", "myController", AdditionalFields = "AccountType", ErrorMessage = "{0} cannot be found.")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.SDF), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Err_Account")]
[Display(Name = "Account")]
public string Account { get; set; }
```

As you can tell, I do server side validation to verify (if the `domain` radio is selected) that the domain account exists. If the `local` radio is selected, my validation method automatically allows it.

My validation method looks like this:

```
public JsonResult ValidateUserID(string Account, string AccountType)
{
    if (AccountType.Equals("Domain"))
    {
        //code to check domain account 
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The problem I am facing is, if the user selects `Local`, then types in a local name. The validation comes back as true, so no error is displayed. If the user then changes the radio button to `Domain` the `Account` field isn't re-validated.

So the user can bypass the AD lookup that I do for domain account.

What do you guys suggest is the best way to get this field revalidated?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should definitely validate the data when it's submitted.  User validation is helpful, but don't trust it to gate your process completely.
2. You could have two separate fields that are used, and make one visible when the domain radio option is selected, and the other visible when the local radio button is selected; I'm not 100% sure, but I have a feeling this would be easier to do in JavaScript (jQuery or the like) on the page rather than server side.  This way your user facing validation code will be properly executed.

Just keep in mind, even if you pursue option 2, you still should validate the data on submit!  Never trust that data being POSTed is already validated.  If you do choose option 2, you can have your submit logic check which radio button is checked and use the correct property to create the account.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It made me think a little more outside the box. it just dawned on me, and I actually think that if I just empty the `Account` field text box whenever the radiobutton selection changes, it may solve my issue. I will try this when I get back.

Comment: Dan, you have opened my eyes to verifying my data is valid after it is submitted. I am new-ish to developing outside of something on my own. I know I can return my model from my controller to re-display the data the user previously entered. However, with the data-annotation method of validationg a form, how do I display the error messages when I return the model that contains invalid data.

Comment: You could have an errorMessage property on the model or put something in the ViewBag.  I'd lean towards keeping it in the model - I don't especially like the ViewBag.